# CSS - position background image when set with background color

Tags: css

I have a code pen here - https://codepen.io/mt-ttmt/pen/yjKPZZ

I can set the background color of an element and set a background image

Is it posssible to set the size and position of the backgorund image and not effect the background color.

```
.content{
  background:  url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1' viewBox='0 0 10 6'%3E%3Cpath d='M1.7.3A1 1 0 1 0 .3 1.7l4 4a1 1 0 0 0 1.4 0l4-4A1 1 0 1 0 8.3.3L5 3.58 1.7.29z' fill='red'/%3E%3C/svg%3E"),linear-gradient(to bottom, white, #999);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  /* This effects the background color as well*/

  /*  background-size: 20px;
      background-position: 2px 5px; 
  */

  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

Comment: You're mixing shorthand and longhand properties and overwriting them in the process. What's the desired final product? Also post a [mcve] in your question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you simply need to specify **two values**, each one for each layer separated by a `,` because a single value will affect both of them.

```css
.content{
  background-image:  
  url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1' viewBox='0 0 10 6'%3E%3Cpath d='M1.7.3A1 1 0 1 0 .3 1.7l4 4a1 1 0 0 0 1.4 0l4-4A1 1 0 1 0 8.3.3L5 3.58 1.7.29z' fill='red'/%3E%3C/svg%3E"),
  linear-gradient(to bottom, white, #999);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 
    20px,
    100% 100%;
   background-position: 
    2px 5px,
    0 0; 
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  
</div>
```

Or use the value directly within the background property and no need to specify values for the gradient:

```css
.content{
  background:  
  url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1' viewBox='0 0 10 6'%3E%3Cpath d='M1.7.3A1 1 0 1 0 .3 1.7l4 4a1 1 0 0 0 1.4 0l4-4A1 1 0 1 0 8.3.3L5 3.58 1.7.29z' fill='red'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") 2px 5px/ 20px no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(to bottom, white, #999);
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify each one separated by `comma` and give the color the default values back which is `auto`.

```css
.content {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1' viewBox='0 0 10 6'%3E%3Cpath d='M1.7.3A1 1 0 1 0 .3 1.7l4 4a1 1 0 0 0 1.4 0l4-4A1 1 0 1 0 8.3.3L5 3.58 1.7.29z' fill='red'/%3E%3C/svg%3E"), linear-gradient(to bottom, white, #999);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px, auto;
  background-position: 2px auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

</div>
```